# Dúvida com Flex-Box CSS

Tags: css, html5

Estou encucado com uma questão do display flex neste trecho de código: https://jsfiddle.net/h6tgnu19/7/

Quero o box fique grudado no topo da página, independente do menu rolar ou não. Que não haja margin nenhuma. Tentei margin: 0 no elemento nav, mas não funfou.

E quanto ao box de pesquisa, não deveria estar também junto com o nav? Como faço para incluir dentro do menu?

Para finalizar. Como poderia fazer o mesmo menu usando block ou inline-block? Tentei e nunca aparecia se quer o box.

Agradecido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa tirar a margem padrão do `body`:

```
body {
    background: #f9f9eb;
    margin: 0; ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ←
}
```

Tire também o `padding` da `<ul>`, que é a classe `.navigation`:

```
.navigation {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; ← ← ← ← ← ← ← ←
    background: #0b5eec;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

A `div` que segura a sua caixa de busca está fora do `nav`:

```
<nav>
   ...
</nav>
<div class="search-box">
   ...
</div>
```

Coloque no final do `nav` e insira no CSS os estilos para centralizar e dar uma margem superior do menu:

```
.search-box{
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 15px;
}
```

**Como fica:**

```css
body {
   background: #f9f9eb;
   margin: 0;
}

nav{
   background: #0b5eec;
}

.navigation {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
   -webkit-box-direction: normal;
   -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: center;
}

.search-box{
    margin: 15px 15px 0;
}

.navigation a {
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   padding: 15px;
   color: white;
}

.navigation a:hover {
   background: #000;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
      <ul class="navigation">
          <li>
              <div class="search-box">
                <label>
                  <input name="search-box" value="Search..."/>
                </label>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Realmente esquecido de colocar a classe na div aqui no arquivo, mas não no link que passei rsrs

Bem isto mesmo no margin 0 do body. Sempre me distraio com isto. 

Quando ao padding do ul não tinha percebido isto. Senão der o padding, fica um espaço no canto esquerdo. Se mudo o justify-content pra flex-end, então este padding não seria necessário, mas pro canto esquerdo é preciso. 

O único problema ainda é a questão da caixa de texto de pesquisa. Quero que fique dentro do box-model dos links da u,. seja ele no canto direito ou esquerdo e não fora do contexto.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que queria como mostrado na resposta?

Comment: Quase isto. Faltou a parte apenas da caixa de texto como expliquei acima.

Quero que a caixa de pesquisa fique dentro do box model como os links. Seja ele no canto esquerdo ou direito. Ele está fora do conteúdo como se iniciasse um novo box model.

Comment: Veja agora.....

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado mesmo. 

Se você não se importar, poderia me explicar sobre as mudanças? 
1. Você retirou o background da ul e passou pra nav; 

Esqueci realmente que a caixa de texto tinha que ser inserido como elemento li.

Comment: Isso mesmo. O background deveria ser na nav e não na UL. Depois centralizei a caixa de busca e coloquei uma margem superior e à direita pra não ficar grudada aos links.

Comment: Realmente muito obrigado. 

1. Você disse que o background tem que ser na nav e não na ul .Alguma explicação técnica/semântica?
2. Por fim, acho que finaliza mesmo minhas dúvidas. Se eu quiser posicionar a caixa de pesquisa para o início ou final do box como faria? Tentei modificar as margin, mas alterava a configuração dos links centrais, que não quero. Tentei o align-item para flex-start e não funcionou. Align-content não tem efeito quando o flexbox tem apenas uma linha. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: É porque o fundo azul estava apenas na UL. E isso estava afetando apenas a UL e não a nav. Vc posiciona a caixa alterando a posição da LI onde ela está. No caso do meu exemplo, eu coloque como primeira LI.