# Como faço para div preencher os cantos da tela?

Tags: html, css

Minha div ao invés dela ficar no topo da tela,ela tem um pequeno espaço (imagem anexada), como resolvo isso?[image: tem espaços no canto esquerdo, e no topo da tela]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvida com Flex-Box CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/310349/d%c3%bavida-com-flex-box-css)

Comment: Outras: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/317187/8063, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/331401/8063

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver meu problema!
o problema é que quando tem um «a href» com uma imagem (ex: «a href="x"» «img src="x"» «/a»  dentro da div, mesmo que mudando as propriedades no css, a div não se move para lugar algum
portanto a solução é:

• Remover «a href» com imagem (use «input type="image" src="imagem.png" onclick="eventoAoSerClicado()"»
• E no css definir:

```css
.classe{
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Esse espaço corresponde ao `padding` padrão que os navegadores aplica ao BODY, para solucionar, basta dar um reset com a seguinte instrução CSS.

```
body{
    padding: 0;
}
```